# how to send message from websocket client to Akka Source using Akka Streams in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an Akka Source that streams numbers using Play Akka WebSocket. The websocket client can send filter message such as 0 or 1 to get even or odd messages.

I do not understand how to send the filter to the Source.

Appreciate any feedback

```
def numbersSource(filter: Int) =
  Source(1 to 1000)
  .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
  .filter{ e =>
    filter match {
      case 0 =>
        e % 2 == 0
      case 1 =>
        e % 2 != 0
      case _ =>
        true
    }
  }.map(_.toString)

def testFlow(): Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[String]
       .filter { msg =>
           //message from ws client
           println(">>"+ msg)
          //validate
          msg != null && !msg.isEmpty
       }
       .via(Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(Sink.ignore, numbersSource(1)))
  }

def testWSFlow ():WebSocket = {

  WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] {

     case rh if sameOriginCheck(rh) =>
         Future.successful(
      Right(testFlow()))

     case rejected =>
      LOGGER.error(s"Request $rejected failed same origin check")
       Future.successful {
         Left(Forbidden("forbidden"))
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "send the filter to the source"?

Comment: What are you seeing?

Comment: In the sample code,  I am send value 1 to the numbersSource. How can i send "msg" from client to the numbersSource.

Comment: You're not sending anything to the source. You're creating a source each time you call `numbersSource` with some argument.

Comment: Can the argument be the message from the websocket client?

Comment: Sure, but it wouldn't be very meaningful because that means for each element consumed from the web socket, you'll create another source with some subset of 1000 elements.

Comment: Yes, each new web socket client will get a new source but a new source is not created per element consumed by  a websocket client. Still do not understand how to pass client filter to source.

Comment: Calling `def numbersSource` will return a new `Source` with every call. I promise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183974/discussion-between-vms-and-erip).